# Okay to install CWM Recovery on Galaxy Nexus 3 GT-i9250M?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-nexus, clockworkmod-recovery

This [article](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/latest-clockworkmod-cwm-recovery-for-samsung-galaxy-nexus-gsm-one-click-installer-46704/) is very explicit that installing CWM recovery is only for the GT-i9250 and that the:

> process here is not for other variants of Samsung Galaxy Nexus, like: GT-i515, GT-i516, GT-L700, i9250T, etc.

However this [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=22580054&postcount=5) says:

> There are no hardware differences, just tweaked software (specifically Radios)

Is there any real risk to installing CWM Recovery on the GT-i9250M?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any real risk to installing CWM Recovery on the GT-i9250M?

**Short answer** : *No*

More information :

> between Install `Recovery`, there is many reasons or problems or other Something you should attend ...

Do not Power off Device. Device maybe at `Flashing` or `Install CWM`
Proccess can Break or Turn Off Completly.

or other something ...

but there's not fear or escaped from this Proccess.

Most of the Time, you can Flash a `Stock Rom` With `Odin` then, your Device is availabe for use.
**But** :

you need Special CWM for your Device, ( Special For `GT-i9250M` ).